# Why isn't the electric quadrupole moment always zero?

Tags: nuclear-physics, multipole-expansion

We know that the electric quadrupole moment ($Q$) describes whether the nucleus of an atom is prolate ($Q<0$), oblate ($Q>0$) or spherical ($Q=0$). We also know that 
$$Q=\frac{2j-1}{2(j+1)}Q_0,$$
where
\begin{align}
Q_0
&=\frac{1}{e}\int_V \rho(r)(3\cos^2\theta-1)r^2\:\mathrm dV
\\ &=\frac{1}{e}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^R\rho(r)(3\cos^2\theta-1)r^2r^2\sin\theta \:\mathrm dr\mathrm d\theta \mathrm d\phi
\end{align}
and
$$Q_0=\frac{1}{e}\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm d\phi\int_0^r r^4\mathrm dr\int_0^\pi (3\cos^2\theta\sin\theta-\sin\theta)\:\mathrm d\theta.$$ 
But we also have the following: 
$$\int_0^\pi (3\cos^2\theta\sin\theta-\sin\theta)\:\mathrm d\theta=0,$$
 which means that $Q_0=0$ and thus $Q=0$, meaning that every atomic nucleus is spherical... What's the catch?

Comment: What is $Q_0$ supposed to represent?

Comment: Are you sure that last integral is zero?  It doesn't look so to me.

Comment: @garyp Yes, it's zero - it's the inner product of $Y_{2,0}$ with $Y_{0,0}$ over the sphere. Why the OP has dropped the angular dependence of $\rho$, on the other hand, is beyond me.

Comment: Wolfram alpha agrees... $Q_0$ is the classical definition of the electric quadrupole moment, and extending it to $Q$ gives the quantum mechanical interpretation.

Comment: I wasn't aware that there is an angular dependance on the charge density...?

Comment: @ODP Why on Earth would you assume there's no angular dependence? You are explicitly trying to describe non-spherical nuclei, right?

Comment: Why on Each would you not be observable enough to recognise the fact that this entire problem has been established?

Answer (score 1):

The full form of the expression for $Q_0$ is
$$
Q_0=\frac{1}{e}\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm d\phi\int_0^r r^4\mathrm dr\int_0^\pi (3\cos^2(\theta)-1)\sin(\theta)\:\rho(r,\theta,\phi)\:\mathrm d\theta.
$$
If you assume that $\rho(r,\theta,\phi)$ has no angular dependence, i.e. that your nucleus is spherical, then indeed the inner integral reduces to
$$
\int_0^\pi (3\cos^2(\theta)-1)\sin(\theta) \:\mathrm d\theta=0,
$$
giving you $Q=0$. If you do not makes such an assumption, you cannot get rid of the $\theta$ dependence of $\rho$ in that inner integral, which can make it nonzero.

In other words, yes: spherical nuclei are spherical. Non-spherical nuclei are not.

Comment: Ah OK, so my mistake here is in assuming that the charge density has no angular dependence...